# How to select radio when label has active class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a website where you can select a couple of options to create your own boat. I need to select radio buttons that are hidden behind a label, so in order to select them I'm writing some JS that does that exact thing.

Here is a small amount of code that contains the particular problem (this code is used in the whole website).

```
<div class="row specs">
    <div class="subtitle">Hull Colour</div>
    <div class="fourcol">
        <label class="item" id="white">
            <img src="images/8meter-outboard.jpg"> 
            <div class="price">Orange</div>
            <input class="form-input" data-color="white" name="color" type="radio" value="white" id="white_radio" />
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="fourcol">
        <label class="item" id="Test">
            <img src="images/8meter-outboard.jpg"> 
            <div class="price">Grey</div>
            <input data-color="grey" name="color" type="radio" value="Test">
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="fourcol last">
        <label class="item" id="orange">
            <img src="images/8meter-outboard.jpg"> 
            <div class="price">White</div>
            <input data-color="orange" name="color" type="radio" value="orange">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

the JS:

```
$('.item').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('done');
      document.getElementById('this').checked = true;
    });
```

Without my Javascript, this markup seems to work. I want to put the display of the `<input>` on none at the end

Comment: If you use the `for` attribute on the label, it will trigger the input that has the same ID. Is it a requirement to us a JS solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize native `HTML` to achieve what you are trying to do.  As Josh Sanger mentioned, when the `for` attribute is assigned to a `label`, a hook into the `input` for that label is instantiated automatically.  As long as the targeted input has a match `id` attribute it will be linked.  Once that hook has been made, you can use some basic `jQuery` selector mechanics to add classes to the HTML elements that you want appear differently.

Make certain that the `input` tag for the `label` is within the `label` so that bound click events will properly trigger it.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(e) {
  var colorDiv = $(this).closest($('div.fourcol')).find($('.price'));
  var removeSelected = $('div.fourcol').find($('.price').not($(this)));
  $(removeSelected).removeClass('done');
  $(colorDiv).addClass('done');
});
```

```css
.orange,
.gray,
.white {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: .79em;
  text-align: center;
}
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
  border: solid 1px orange;
}
.gray {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
}
.white {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: solid 1px #FFF;
}
input {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: none;
}
.row.specs {
  width: 250px;
}
.price.noColor {
  border: solid 1px #ACE;
}
.noColor {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: red;
}
.fourcol {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-family: arial;
}
.done {
  border: dashed 1px green;
}
.price.noColor.done {
  border: dashed 1px green;
}

body{
  background-color: #DDE;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row specs">
  <div class="subtitle">Hull Colour</div>
  <div class="fourcol">
    <label class="item" for="orange_radio">
      <div class="price orange">Orange</div>
    </label>
    <input data-color="orange" name="color" type="radio" value="orange" id="orange_radio" />
  </div>

  <div class="fourcol">
    <label class="item" for="grey_radio">
      <div class="price gray">Grey</div>
    </label>
    <input data-color="grey" name="color" type="radio" value="gray" id="grey_radio" />
  </div>

  <div class="fourcol">
    <label class="item" for="white_radio">
      <div class="price white">White</div>
    </label>
    <input data-color="white" name="color" type="radio" value="white" id="white_radio" />
  </div>

  <div class="fourcol">
    <label class="item" for="noColor_radio">
      <div class="price noColor">X</div>
    </label>
    <input data-color="nocolor" name="color" type="radio" value="nocolor" id="noColor_radio" />
  </div>
</div>
```